# How can view details of a Google Docs' document while editing it?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I want to be able to view the Folder (location) and other info (file size, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- go to **File**
- select **Document details...**

[image: 5]

---

> **Size —**
>
> **Storage used:
>   0 bytes - Google Docs files are free**

[image: 2]